# Why is my Bootstrap column centered instead of left-aligned?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using standard Bootstrap 3 CSS.

Image of my issue:

[image: rendered error]

My HTML is below:

```
<div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 relative text-center">
    <h3 class="text-center">Tell Us More About Yourself:</h3>
    <label for="motto" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Motto:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input id="motto" type="text" class="form-control" name="motto" ng-model="profile.UserParams.Motto">
    </div>
    </br>
    </br>
    <label for="occupation" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Occupation:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input id="occupation" type="text" class="form-control" name="occupation" ng-model="profile.UserParams.Occupation">
    </div>
    </br>
    </br>
    <label for="location" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Location:</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input id="location" type="text" class="form-control" name="location" ng-model="profile.UserParams.Location">
    </div>
    </br>
    </br>
    <button style="margin-top:25px;" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" ng-click="updateProfile()">Update Profile</button>
</div>
<div style="margin-top:50px;" class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 relative text-center">
    <h3>Change Your Password:</h3>
    <div class="form-group">
        <form name="changePassword">
            <label for="password" class="col-sm-4 control-label">New Password (must be at least 5 characters long):</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" ng-minlength="5" ng-model="user.password" required>
            </div>
            </br>
            </br>
            <label for="cpassword" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Confirm New Password:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
                <input id="cpassword1" type="password" class="form-control" name="cpassword" ng-minlength="5" ng-model="user.confirmPassword" compare-to="user.password" required>
                <div ng-messages="changePassword.cpassword.$error" style="color:maroon" role="alert">
                    <div ng-message="compareTo">Your passwords must match!</div>
                    <div ng-message="minlength">Your password is too short!</div>
                </div>
            </div>
            </br>
            </br>
            <button style="margin-top:25px;" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" ng-click="changePasswordFunction()">Change Password</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    </br>
    </br>
</div>
```

I would expect the `<form>` in the HTML to mirror the HTML/CSS above (Tell US More About Yourself), but instead I get the `Confirm New Password` label stuck in the center even though it should `float:left;` and be under the `New Password` label. The form doesn't have any special CSS. Why is `Confirm New Password` being centered like that when it is a `col-sm-4`?

My current viewport is a laptop that reaches the `lg` breakpoint, but oddly enough this error only shows up between 768px and about 1600px. When I use the Chrome Dev Tools to set a wide desktop viewport I get the right format... but I don't understand why that is given my breakpoints.

Comment: because of floating .. you should wrap them inside `row` ... you are not following the bootstrap rules, you have to use container and rows

Comment: @TemaniAfif but I don't wrap the others in a row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are facing **floating** issue as you are not wraping your element inside `.row` as you can see in this question : [Floated elements of variable height push siblings down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15098223/floated-elements-of-variable-height-push-siblings-down)

So here is what you are having if you don't use container/row provided with bootstrap :

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="col-xs-4">
  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
</div>
<div class="col-xs-8">
  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lore
</div>
<div class="col-xs-4">
  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsu
</div>
<div class="col-xs-8">
  lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
</div>
```

And if you correctly structure your elements following bootstrap rules you obtain this:

```css
div {
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lore
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-4">
      lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsu
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-8">
      lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use bootstrap `row` `column` rules for the aligned layout mentioned [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#grid) like below inside the `form`

> Note: See the following snippet in expand preview

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 relative text-center">
      <h3 class="text-center">Tell Us More About Yourself</h3>
      <div class="row">
        <label for="motto" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Motto:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input id="motto" type="text" class="form-control" name="motto" ng-model="profile.UserParams.Motto">
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <br>
      <div class="row">
        <label for="occupation" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Occupation:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input id="occupation" type="text" class="form-control" name="occupation" ng-model="profile.UserParams.Occupation">
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <br>
      <div class="row">
        <label for="location" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Location:</label>
        <div class="col-sm-8">
          <input id="location" type="text" class="form-control" name="location" ng-model="profile.UserParams.Location">
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <br>
      <button style="margin-top:25px;" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" ng-click="updateProfile()">Update Profile</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div style="margin-top:50px;" class="col-sm-12 col-lg-6 col-lg-offset-3 relative text-center">
      <h3>Change Your Password:</h3>
      <div class="form-group">
        <form name="changePassword">
          <div class="row">
            <label for="password" class="col-sm-4 control-label">New Password (must be at least 5 characters long):</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" ng-minlength="5" ng-model="user.password" required>
            </div>
          </div>
          <br>
          <br>
          <div class="row">
            <label for="cpassword" class="col-sm-4 control-label">Confirm New Password:</label>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <input id="cpassword1" type="password" class="form-control" name="cpassword" ng-minlength="5" ng-model="user.confirmPassword" compare-to="user.password" required>
              <div ng-messages="changePassword.cpassword.$error" style="color:maroon" role="alert">
                <div ng-message="compareTo">Your passwords must match!</div>
                <div ng-message="minlength">Your password is too short!</div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <br>
          <br>
          <button style="margin-top:25px;" class="btn btn-lg btn-danger" ng-click="changePasswordFunction()">Change Password</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this also need to be done on the first part of the code (even if we don't visually see an issue, it remains not well strcutured.)

Comment: just missing the container at the first and it will be good ;)

Answer (score -2):

There is no need to float them, if you are using bootstrap, just use rows and columns, wrap elements inside those classes. Float is what is messing with your style. Also, I would recommend using css Flexbox in the future, it is much better and more flexible than bootstrap.

Comment: `There is no need to float them` bootstrap 3 use floating elements and he's not floating them ... and Bootstrap 4 is using flex, so he should upgrade to bootstrap 4 if he need to use flex .. and i don't agree with `it is much better and more flexible than bootstrap.` : Bootstrap 3 even if it rely on float can be a very good way to handle layouts

Comment: If you are creating custom layouts, it is much easier to handle styles using flex than bootstrap, but hey, to each his own @TemaniAfif

Comment: but bootstrap is also using flex :) and can handle custom layout as well ;)