# Bad layout with `float:left`

Tags: html, css

EDIT: You can see an example in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zmbq/8kun9d3j/1/).

I've inherited an old website that uses absolutely no responsive framework. Everything was done by hand, and it shows. The website was in-use until about a year ago, and now I need to revive it.

In one of the pages there are four panels that should be ordered like this:

```
A    B
C    D
```

This is done with the following style:

```
.panel-container {
   float: left;
   width: 48%;
   text-align: center;
   margin-bottom: 2%;
}
```

Up until a year ago, everything was fine. However, now when I try to display the page I get something like this:

```
A    B
     C
D
```

Only when the window is large enough (by zooming out to 70%) is the page displayed properly.

I tried changing the `width` in the CSS, and things became even stranger! Setting a width of 32% showed the following, as expected:

```
A    B     C
D
```

Setting the width to anything greater than 33% resulted in the problematic layout.

I'm stumped, I'm not even sure how to proceed from here, other than redoing the site with a flexbox.

Comment: Please include a snippet of HTML to go along with the associated CSS. Display-related problems are much easier to solve with a [**MCVE**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: can't possibly tell without seeing html. Look at the content as well; isn't there an element inside one of the boxes that pushes away something? But going flexbox would be my personal choice actually.

Comment: Maybe refactor every page and use flex-box instead. That will save you so much time instead of fixing old code.

Comment: duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15098223/floated-elements-of-variable-height-push-siblings-down

Comment: I've removed the tag `flexbox`, since the question is not about that technology, but rather about `float`.

Comment: @TylerRoper, you're right of course. I've added a JSFiddle with the relevant part from the actual code (which, I reiterate, was *not* written by me...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because your `A` has a bigger height:

```css
.panel-container {
  float: left;
  width: 48%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  height: 100px;
}

.bigger {
  height: 200px;
}

.clearfix::after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="clearfix">
  <div class="panel-container bigger">
  A
  </div>
  <div class="panel-container">
  B
  </div>
  <div class="panel-container">
  C
  </div>
  <div class="panel-container">
  D
  </div>
</div>
<hr />
<div class="clearfix">
  <div class="panel-container">
  A
  </div>
  <div class="panel-container">
  B
  </div>
  <div class="panel-container">
  C
  </div>
  <div class="panel-container">
  D
  </div>
</div>
```

You could simply add a `clear` for odd items:

```css
.panel-container {
  float: left;
  width: 48%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
  height: 100px;
}

.panel-container:nth-child(odd) {
  clear: both;
}

.bigger {
  height: 200px;
}

.clearfix::after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="clearfix">
  <div class="panel-container bigger">
  A
  </div>
  <div class="panel-container">
  B
  </div>
  <div class="panel-container">
  C
  </div>
  <div class="panel-container">
  D
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, I'm not sure whether this is indeed the case, but real impressive! I'll give it a try shortly.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not the case. I'll try to create an example of this.

Comment: OK, added an example, note the JSFiddle link at the top of the question

Comment: Yes it is as I wrote @zmbq. Have a look at this updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8kun9d3j/3/). When you inspect the elements then you will see that the first element is less than a pixel bigger as the second one.

Comment: Amazing! The height looked identical to me, as I never considered looking at subpixel values. I hate CSS...