# How can I make multi dimensional divs without using additional wrapper div?

Tags: html, css

I am using the following code.

**Note:** I don't want to wrap the divs with additional div
But I am facing some problem.

```css
.col{
    float: left;
    width: calc(100% / 3);
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 0 16px;
    background-color:red;
}
```

```html
<div>Other Div</div>
<div class="col">1</div>
<div class="col">2</div>
<div class="col">3</div>
<div class="col">4</div>
<div class="col">5</div>
```

Comment: It works just fine for me. Are you sure there's no more code interfering?

Comment: me too! what exactly is the problem?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Floated elements of variable height push siblings down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15098223/floated-elements-of-variable-height-push-siblings-down)

Comment: Also, you should use CSS Grid for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.col{
    display: inline-block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: calc((100% / 3) - 7px); /*Lawrence Cherone remark*/
    margin: 2px;
    padding: 0 16px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div>Other Div</div>
<div class="col">1</div>
<div class="col">2</div>
<div class="col">3</div>
<div class="col">4</div>
<div class="col">5</div>
```

Comment: I don't want to wrap the divs with additional div.

Comment: you didn't mention it in your question

Comment: Yeah, I just put the code what I have used. Can you help me please?

Comment: Yes, of course, I want to help, but why don't you want to wrap the blocks in a container? It will be right.

Comment: I know this solution but I am working in a Blogger Theme. It has no way to wrap additional div manually.

Comment: I redid this code

Comment: you can also do more then one sum in `calc()`, i.e `width: calc((100% / 3) - 36px);` which would actully fit 3 in across the whole page instead of a chunk of whitespace.

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone, yes you are right. Let me include your comment in my answer.

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone, i entered your name as the author of this line of code :))

Comment: np, it works nice, the `- Npx` countering the margin

Comment: now it's even better than it was. I didn't think at all about the need to subtract pixels to stretch blocks